# OpenCV 2.3 C++ basic image processing

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

What is the best way to open an image, manually manipulate the pixels as floats, normalize the pixels back to 8bit int values (0-255) and save the new image.

I found deferment codes use different variable types and commands, should i use Iplimage or mat, imread, and so on...

i would really appreciate a code example

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the tutorial section provided in the OpenCV docs: [OpenCV Tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html). Especially **"Introduction to OpenCV"** and **"core module. The Core Functionality"** are the chapters you should be most interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html#load-save-image). This gives the basic code sample.